# How to get company posts from LinkedIn via API?

Tags: php, http-status-code-404, linkedin-api

I would like to get the company posts from LinkedIn in PHP. What request should I use to ask for the post?

I  try to use PHP library ["zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client"](https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client). I have created LinkedIn application with a verified access to the company. I wrote the code that get LinkenIn access token. I try to use [GET 'companies' request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820487/linkedin-company-feed) but I receive errors 404 or 410.

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    // add Composer autoloader
    include_once __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'vendor/autoload.php';

    // import client class
    use LinkedIn\Client;
    use LinkedIn\Scope;
    use LinkedIn\AccessToken;

    // instantiate the Linkedin client
    $client = new Client(
        'correct client id',
        'correct client secret'
    );
    $scopes = [
        Scope::READ_BASIC_PROFILE
      ];
    $client->setRedirectUrl("correct return address, which is the same as URL of current script");
    $loginUrl = $client->getLoginUrl($scopes);

    if (isset($_GET) && isset($_GET['code']))
    {
        $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken($_GET['code']);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
        $client->setApiRoot('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/'); //I've tried to use 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/' too
        $client->setApiHeaders([
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'x-li-format' => 'json',
            'X-Restli-Protocol-Version' => '2.0.0', // use protocol v2
        ]);
        $posts = $client->get('/v1/companies/10239645/updates?format=json'); 
        //I've tried to use '/v2/companies/10239645/updates?format=json' 
        //and '/companies/10239645/updates?format=json'
        var_dump($posts);
        die();
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: ' . $loginUrl);
    }
```

I receive client errors ('GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException') depending on the address of the request:

- "`GET https://api.linkedin.com/companies/10239645/updates?format=json` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response"
- "`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies/10239645/updates?format=json` resulted in a `410 Gone` response: { "errorCode": 0, "message": "This resource is no longer available under v1 APIs", "requestId": "CH17ME6WK6", "s (truncated...)";
- "`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/companies/10239645/updates?format=json` resulted in a `404 Not Found` response: {"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Resource companies does not exist","status":404}".

I would like to get the company posts from LinkedIn.

Is the request 'companies' is disabled now? What request (and request address) should I use? How to get the company posts from LinkedIn now? What is wrong in my code? Could you help me?

Comment: Hello Kamil, any news on the subject ?  I'm used with several wrappers, but am struggling with Linkedin.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You should use the Find [Share By Owner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#find-shares-by-owner) endpoint. This is a v2 endpoint so the first thing to do is to [Change default API root](https://github.com/zoonman/linkedin-api-php-client#change-default-api-root) as  described in the doc of the SDK:

```
  $client->setApiRoot('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/');
```

Then try with:

```
$posts = $client->get('shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:10239645');
```

NB: Check you are asking for the right Scopes during the OAuth flow (See the [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#permissions) section at the beginning of the page) and that your App have the right permission (See the product section in the developer app console)

Comment: Sending request to 'shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:10239645' causes error "`GET https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:10239645` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"serviceErrorCode":0,"message":"Invalid query parameters passed to request","status":400}".

Comment: @KamilSzmit very strange, you can debug the endpoint with your browser with the url: `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:10239645&oauth2_access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>`  using a valid access token

Comment: The address https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares?q=owners&owners=urn:li:organization:10239645&oauth2_access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN> returns {"serviceErrorCode":100,"message":"Not enough permissions to access: GET-owners /shares","status":403} Does this query require a product 'Marketing Developer Platform' added to the LinkedIn application? Does this query really return the LinkedIn posts of the company?

Comment: I am having a same issue.

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: @KamilSzmit yes it requires additional permission as [page managment](https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog/marketing/page-management) is part of the [marketing development platform](https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog) or whatever LinkedIn calls it

Comment: @Matteo I have the necessary permissions and still get ```Resource organization does not exist', 'status': 404 ``` also with your suggestion one would only get the posts that a specific individual posted via company page and not all company posts?