# How to display LinkedIn feeds on my website in php?

Tags: php

I would like to show my company Linkedin feed on my website (a WordPress site),For fetching LinkedIn feeds, i created LinkedIn company page and post some feeds on that page. After that i created app on https://www.linkedin.com/developer/, i and got client ID, client Secret Key, i also got access token of my app. But i'm not understanding, how can i make LinkedIn API so that i can display LinkedIn feeds on my website. Actually i don't want to display feeds by iframe way. I want display feeds on my custom html. I have tried Using PHP LinkedIn SDK as following.

```
$li = new LinkedIn(array(
    'api_key' => "client secret",
    'api_secret' => "client ID",
    'callback_url' => "redirecturl"
));

$token = $li->setAccessToken('Your access token');

$feeds = $li->fetch('GET', '/v2/companies/company-id/updates?event-type=status-update&start=0&count=6&format=json');

$posts = $li->get('/companies/79097881/updates/');

$pages = json_decode(file_get_contents($posts));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($pages);
```

But i didn't get anything. So please provide me some solution.

Comment: I am not sure if this link may be usefull, but try to read it: https://blog.hubspot.com/website/best-wordpress-plugins-for-linkedin

Comment: What's the value of `$posts`?

Comment: Actully it gives nothing in the $posts variable, i think the url is not correct

Comment: it gives nothing in the $posts variable, i think the URL is not correct. actually i created app in https://www.linkedin.com/developers/ and get client Id, client secret key, also add products 'Share on LinkedIn', 'Sign In with LinkedIn'. But when tried to add the product 'Marketing Developer Platform' then my request has been cancelled

Comment: Hi  
Lawrence Cherone
I have tried everything which is written on this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31820487/linkedin-company-feed and used this file https://github.com/ashwinks/PHP-LinkedIn-SDK/blob/master/LinkedIn/LinkedIn.php and tried fetching feeds by doing above code.